# Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens

Tags: php, html, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the next problem. when try publish like with the api of facebook get me the next error
'Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens'
Please help me

I tried with the token of user and it's not work, I would using the function object likes with my token of user
I add I am using php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Like post at Facebook via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875940/like-post-at-facebook-via-api)